# Prove fact about integral $\int_0^1 \frac{x^7}{(e^x+e^{-x})\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to prove that $\displaystyle 0,02<\int_0^1 \frac{x^7}{(e^x+e^{-x})\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx<0,05$? I tried to use mean value theorems, but i failed.

Comment: What is $0,02 & 0,05$ is it $0.05$

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $e^x + e^{-x}$, on $[0, 1]$, is no greater than $3.1$. And $\sqrt{1 + x^2}$ is no greater than $\sqrt{2}$. So your integrand is no less than 
$$
\frac{x^7}{3.1 \sqrt{2}} \ge \frac{x^7}{4.4}
$$

Now integrate.

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

Note that $2\le e^x+e^{-x}\le e+e^{-1}$ and $x\le \sqrt{1+x^2}\le \sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$e^x+e^{-x}\geq 2$ by AM-GM, and $\sqrt{1+x^2}>x$

So the integral is less than integration of $x^6/2$ from $0$ to $1$, which equals $1/14>0.05$.

$e^x+e^{−x}$, is less than $3.1$ in $(0,1]$ And $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ is less than $2√2$. So your integrand is greater than
$x^7/3.1\times\sqrt{2}$

Now integrate.

Comment: 1/14 is greater than 0,05, but thanks for your idea!

Comment: But maybe there is my mistake with values...